# Vue Refresh page on param id changes for the same page

Tags: vue.js

I have a function where I am passing an id. The param id in the URL is changing but the view is not refreshing, I get the same content. It works fine if I am indifferent page.

```
  <a @click.prevent="user(userId)"> </a>

methods:
  user(id) {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'user', params: { id } });
      },
```

Comment: See Vue Router [Reacting to Params Changes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

Answer (score 7):

Use a unique `key` on the router view:

```html
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

The unique key tells Vue to use a different instance of the component instead of reusing the existing one whenever the route changes. With `$route.fullPath`, any unique param will be enough to make the key unique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am not using router-view in this page.

Comment: Why / how are you using Vue router without a `<router-view>`? If you just mean that this component is a route and not the parent, yes I know. Put the `key` on the `<router-view>` anyway, wherever it is

Comment: genius !!! simple and effective !

Comment: What if I want to keep the component alive after it is rendered for the first time? This destroys the component when `$route.fullPath` changes.

Comment: @kjmj You probably need `<keep-alive>` depending on what you're trying to do.  See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66216603/2185093)