# Vue 3 keep-alive cache routes

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 `<keep-alive>`. When I don't use `:key` it caches (improperly across different URLs as expected).

By adding

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" v-slot="{ Component }">
  <keep-alive>
    <component :is="Component" />
  </keep-alive>
</router-view>
```

I would think that it only makes an API call if the cache key doesnt exist, so that when I go to a different route and come back, it won't make a second api call.

But when I add `:key="$route.fullPath"` now it makes an API call every single time even if I revisit the same URL?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Vue 3, put the `key` on the `<component>` rather than the `<router-view>`:

```html
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <keep-alive>
    <component :is="Component" :key="$route.fullPath"></component>
  </keep-alive>
</router-view>
```

Comment: Dude awesome... thank you! I have one more side question. I've fixed this on both places that use keep-alive, but there is another part where I use a very complicated tabbed table and it's still cached when I click the different tabs. Do I need to add `:key="some_key"` on the 'outer-most' component which changes based on the tab? (The highest common denominator)

Comment: I should mention that I'm not hiding and showing tabs. I simply have one component like `<base-table :items="items" />` and in that base table are rows. It seems though that when I switch tabs, my "inline edit" rows are crossing between the tabs instead of having that inline edit specific to that tab.

Comment: You're welcome.  It's hard to envision what you're asking in the followup question.  Can you ask it in a more general way that isn't related to your particular setup?

Comment: @Tallboy I don't know why I didn't understand what you were asking before, it's obvious to me now.  You probably need a key on the `<base-table>` that connects it to the current tab.  For example, something like the active tab index.