# Keep-alive is not working when navigating between routes in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, keep-alive, nuxt3

`page.vue:`

```html
<keep-alive>
  <MyFilterComponent />
</keep-alive>
```

I fetch items of Filter-Component in Component itself, and when I navigate between routes it is losing fetched data and its states

Comment: see the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive), notice every example uses dynamic `<component>` element.  maintaining state when navigating between routes would require something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215625/vue-3-keep-alive-cache-routes), or global store (e.g. Pinia), or use of localStorage.